# How to add two files?

Tags: file, psql

How can I have two files in the same .sh file of mine? I have two files:

1. create.sql,
2. update.sql.

I am trying to use something like this:

```
psql \
        -X \
        -U "User" \
        -h "$Host" \
        --dbname "$DB" \
        -f /create.sql \
        -f /update.sql \
```

Is it correct to write like this? 
Or Do I need to use \i for entering two files? How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: That looks reasonable. The absolute path `/` for the files looks a bit strange though. Are you sure those files are stored in the root directory of your filesystem?

Comment: Yes, those two files are stored in the root directory of the filesystem.

Comment: But do you think that writing the two .sql files , one for create and other for update is correct?